# Downloading wikipedia database for offline use

Tags: backup, database, offline-files, wikipedia, zim

Here there are many ZIM files: https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/kiwix/zim/wikipedia/

I want complete English Wikipedia with images... which one should I download?

What is the difference for example between en_all_maxi and en_all_mini?

What en_100 means? etc.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent the wheel? Have you seen [Kiwix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiwix)? if you do want to go it alone, read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download

Comment: @Tetsujin kiwix for windows currently is available in 64-bit version only and i don't have 64 bit windows at the moment... but i wanted to download wikipedia database in advance

Comment: @Tetsujin and yes i have read that wikipedia guide already, but there is no answer to my question there

Comment: I would question the wisdom of trying to mirror all of Wikipedia on a 32-bit machine.

Comment: @Tetsujin why not? it is just for offline personal use later. i think even an old PC can handle that enough to be more or less usable. by the way isn't it possible that someone has installed a 32 bit version of windows on a 64 bit hardware? i can install 64 bit windows later or use my storage media with another PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems en_100 refers to a category, or it could mean top 100.

As for the sizing:

> Mini: only the introduction of each article, plus the infobox. Saves about 95% of space vs. the full version.
> nopic: full articles, but no images. About 75% smaller than the full version
> Maxi: the default full version.

You might want https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/kiwix/zim/wikipedia/wikipedia_en_all_maxi_2020-07.zim
and
https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/kiwix/zim/wikipedia/wikipedia_en_all_maxi_2020-06.zim

Those files are about 100 GB each.

See: https://www.kiwix.org/en/documentation/